# How to get all user data within office365 people page [directory/all users] using ms-graph

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` to get the list of users, but the total number, which is `5140`, is greater than what I see under the people page entry: `directory/all users`, which is `4363`.

[image]
How can I get the correct numbers of users using graph api?

Comment: What is `directory/all users`?

Comment: [enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVxML.png

Answer (score 2):

The "All Users" page you referenced in your link only shows **active** users within your AAD. The `/users` endpoint shows both active and inactive accounts.

Try filtering out disabled accounts using a `$filter` clause:

```
/v1.0/users?$filter=accountEnabled eq 'false'
```

Comment: but this can only work under super user right? since it need user.read.all privilege

Comment: That isn't how it works, no. You need Admin Consent from a tenant admin. Once an Admin has consented to your application, any user can use your app (including `user.read.all`). See https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-user-vs-admin/ for details on how this works.